# What is 198.51.100.2

Tags: networking

I see this IP address in the AWS documentation but I'm confused about what it is.

It's not a [private IP address according to the IANA spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network).

When I [google for it](https://www.google.com/search?q=198.51.100.2) I see it referenced in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) but they don't explain what it's used for. [Other projects](https://github.com/dcos/spartan) appear to treat it as a private address.

It does not appear to be routable from the internet.

What is this IP address used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `198.51.100.0/24` network (TEST-NET-2) is set aside by IANA as one of three documentation networks. You are supposed to use addresses from the three documentation networks for examples in documentation, and those address blocks are not supposed to actually be used in networks.

See the [*IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry*](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml).